# Pointing to /civicrm breaks Wordpress site, 404 HTTP response

Tags: wordpress, configuration

The requested URL /civicrm was not found on this server.
CiviCRM 4.6.3
Wordpress 4.1.1

After having created a campaign widget the example.com/civicrm returns a 404 HTTP response, when clicking on "contribute"?

This instance of Wordpress is running on apache and virtualhosts with other Wordpress installations

Already tried whats here: [Forum CiviCRM](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35005.0)

Thanks keep up the great work!

Comment: > They should be Post Name (%postname%) That setting is here: example.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php Is there a way to use another permalink structure, like /%category%/%postname%/ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can we verify a few things?

What are your WordPress permalinks set to?

They should be Post Name (%postname%)   That setting is here:  example.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php

This will add to your .htaccess file the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Now can you go to example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/setting/uf&reset=1

This is the menu option Adminsiter -> System Settings -> CMS Database Integration.

You should see 'civicrm' in the WordPress Base Page setting.   If not, add it there.

Confirm that there is a WordPress page titled 'CiviCRM' in the list of WordPress Pages: example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page

This page should have a permalink of example.com/civicrm

Once all these settings are in place, you should be good.

Comment: Nice answer, Kevin :)

Comment: Thank you for this. The one thing I hadn't done is change the Permalinks setting from "Default" to "Post name" which fixed everything. This really should be in the documentation somewhere or perhaps I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem because my CiviCRM site is located at url www.blah.com/ and not at www.blah.com/civicrm. I fixed it by clearing the WordPress Base Page setting box (see Kevin's post on how to set the WordPress Base Page)