# Staging Site: staging.site.com/civicrm 404 WordPress

Tags: wordpress, error, configuration, urls, error-page

All paths seem to be set up correctly, I've gone through [Pointing to /civicrm breaks Wordpress site, 404 HTTP response](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/658/pointing-to-civicrm-breaks-wordpress-site-404-http-response) and the forum link posted on there but with no success

So for example staging.site.com/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact will return a 404 error (anything /civicrm returns a 404 error inc "staging.site.com/civicrm") There is a single error in the error log relating

staging.site.com [Fri Mar 10 17:21:10 2017] [error] [pid 2446] mod_negotiation.c(1291): [client 123.123.123.123:52418] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /home/profile/www/staging/civicrm (None could be negotiated).

The CiviCRM page in WordPress exists and every other page works okay, the main production site works okay

I've checked all the resource URLs etc and everything looks good, matches the production version apart from pointing to the staging directory, permalinks are setup, as is the .htaccess file

I've looked up the error in the error.log file and nothing comes up at all related to civi so at a bit of a loss now, hopefully there's something simple to fix!

I'm fairly new to civi, so things that are probably easy fixes I'm not aware of yet! The staging site is a clone of the production site but with everything in the settings file & database changed to the staging directory

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I forgot to put a response here... 
Just to let those know who may have this issue

Adding "Options -MultiViews" to the .htaccess fixed it...

Simple fix but was an environment based issue... There is info about this online but apparently I couldn't put 2 and 2 together!!!

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the CiviVerse!

Check for the presence of the .htaccess files. Depending on how you cloned the site perhaps these were lost.

Comment: Thanks! :)
.htaccess is definitely there, it's strange, all other pages work except the civicrm page
The site was cloned through ssh and then the wp-content folder is version controlled